# Remove matching line after an IP before matching another IP

Tags: awk

How to remove matching lines after an IP before matching another IP?

I got the following data in a text file `output.txt`:

```
1.1.1.1
cc.com
ac.com
1.2.3.4
okok.com
1.1.1.11
abc.com
kkk.net
1.4.4.4
abc.net
xyz.my
ttt.us
okok.com
1.8.3.33
jj.com
cpp.com
```

You can see that each IP has at least 1 domain record below it (each IP must have a least 1 or more domains below it).

I know how to remove the IP using `sed` like below but I don't know how to remove its domains as well:

```
ip="1.1.1.1"
awk -v d=$ip  '$0 != d' $output> tmp && mv tmp $output
```

This will only remove the IP, but how do I remove all the domain belonging to `1.1.1.1` including its IP?

The expected output for the new file to be this after `1.1.1.1` has been removed:

```
1.2.3.4
okok.com
1.1.1.11
abc.com
kkk.net
1.4.4.4
abc.net
xyz.my
ttt.us
okok.com
1.8.3.33
jj.com
cpp.com
```

Comment: Please add tags that you like your problems to be solved with. Don't spam it with ones not needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v ip="$ip" '/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}$/ { # if row matches any IP address
   rem = ($1 == ip)                        # toggle rem if IP matches input
}
!rem' ip.txt                               # print if rem=0
```

```
1.2.3.4
okok.com
1.1.1.11
abc.com
kkk.net
1.4.4.4
abc.net
xyz.my
ttt.us
okok.com
1.8.3.33
jj.com
cpp.com
```

Comment: Insert `-i inplace` in awk command to save changes inline to file.

Comment: `-i inplace` is a GNU AWK extension, isn't it?

Comment: @rethab: Yes that is gnu awk feature

Comment: @anubhava yes, it's working.. and thank you for the code explanation it helped me a lot to learn about awk writing style..

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk` could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk -v RS="([0-9]+\\\\.){3}[0-9]+" -v ip="1.1.1.1" '
prev{
  sub(/\n+$/,"")
  print prev $0
  prev=""
}
RT && RT!=ip{
  prev=RT
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v RS="([0-9]+\\\\.){3}[0-9]+" -v ip="1.1.1.1" ' ##Starting awk program.
##Setting RS as digit dot 3 times then digits here, creating variable ip with
##value which we do not want.
prev{                       ##Checking condition if prev is NOT NULL then do following.
  sub(/\n+$/,"")            ##Substituting new lines till end of line with NULL.  
  print prev $0             ##printing prev and current line here.
  prev=""                   ##Nullifying prev here.
}
RT && RT!=ip{               ##Checking condition if RT NOT NULL and RT not equal to ip
  prev=RT                   ##Then set prev to RT value here.
}'  Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I think you need to add `prev=""` after print